# Groupbox border color change

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Is it possible to change the default grey border of a `GroupBox`to something visible? (for example black or blue?). I found a similar question but related to the `GroupBox` caption not for the border.

Thanks

Comment: Paint the control yourself. It's a pretty simple control to paint.

Comment: i will try.....

Comment: I've sorted out in a different way: get rid of the groupbox, and draw a rectange around the text.
`procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

var TheRect: TRect;
begin
 TheRect := Rect(13,50,250,120);
  Form1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirements you could do two things:

1. Use a third party component (free if possible).
2. create the component your self.

Now for option 1 I strongly recommend FlatStyle open source set of components it contains `TFlatGroupBox` which has what you are asking. This is the [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/c336i59ozey4yue/FLATStyle.rar) to the latest modified version by me (it is compatible with delphi 10 seattle).

For option 2 lets put some criteria for our component

1. It is a group box descendant.(required by your question)
2. It need to have a border color property (required by your question)
3. How about changing the border width.
4. How about changing the style of the border (`psSolid`, `psDash`, `psDot`, `psDashDot`, `psDashDotDot`, `psClear`,
   `psInsideFrame`, `psUserStyle`, `psAlternate`).

this is yet another modified version of `TFlatGroupBox` with added features

```
unit TFlatGroupBoxUnit;

interface

{$I DFS.inc}

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Forms, Classes, Graphics, Controls, ExtCtrls, FlatUtilitys;

type
  TFlatGroupBox = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FTransparent: Boolean;
    FUseAdvColors: Boolean;
    FAdvColorBorder: TAdvColors;
    FBorderColor: TColor;
    FBorder: TGroupBoxBorder;
    FBorderWidth:integer;
    Fborderstyle:Tpenstyle;
    procedure SetAdvColors (Index: Integer; Value: TAdvColors);
    procedure SetUseAdvColors (Value: Boolean);
    procedure CMEnabledChanged (var Message: TMessage); message CM_ENABLEDCHANGED;
    procedure CMTextChanged (var Message: TWmNoParams); message CM_TEXTCHANGED;
    procedure SetColors(const Index: Integer; const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetBorder(const Value: TGroupBoxBorder);
    procedure CMSysColorChange (var Message: TMessage); message CM_SYSCOLORCHANGE;
    procedure CMParentColorChanged (var Message: TWMNoParams); message CM_PARENTCOLORCHANGED;
    procedure CMDialogChar (var Message: TCMDialogChar); message CM_DIALOGCHAR;
    procedure WMSize (var Message: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
    procedure WMMove (var Message: TWMMove); message WM_MOVE;
    procedure SetTransparent (const Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetBorderWidth(value:integer);
    procedure SetBorderStyle(value:TPenStyle);
  protected
    procedure CalcAdvColors;
    procedure Paint; override;
   {$IFDEF DFS_COMPILER_4_UP}
    procedure SetBiDiMode(Value: TBiDiMode); override;
   {$ENDIF}
  public
    constructor Create (AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property Transparent: Boolean read FTransparent write SetTransparent default false;
    property BorderWidth: integer read FBorderWidth write SetBorderWidth default 1;
    property BorderStyle:Tpenstyle read FBorderStyle write SetBorderStyle default psSolid;
    property Align;
    property Cursor;
    property Caption;
    property Font;
    property ParentFont;
    property Color;
    property ParentColor;
    property PopupMenu;
    property ShowHint;
    property ParentShowHint;
    property Enabled;
    property Visible;
    property TabOrder;
    property TabStop;
    property Hint;
    property HelpContext;
    property ColorBorder: TColor index 0 read FBorderColor write SetColors default $008396A0;
    property Border: TGroupBoxBorder read FBorder write SetBorder default brFull;
    property AdvColorBorder: TAdvColors index 0 read FAdvColorBorder write SetAdvColors default 50;
    property UseAdvColors: Boolean read FUseAdvColors write SetUseAdvColors default false;
   {$IFDEF DFS_COMPILER_4_UP}
    property Anchors;
    property BiDiMode write SetBidiMode;
    property Constraints;
    property DragKind;
    property DragMode;
    property DragCursor;
    property ParentBiDiMode;
    property DockSite;
    property OnEndDock;
    property OnStartDock;
    property OnDockDrop;
    property OnDockOver;
    property OnGetSiteInfo;
    property OnUnDock;
   {$ENDIF}
   {$IFDEF DFS_DELPHI_5_UP}
    property OnContextPopup;
   {$ENDIF}
    property OnClick;
    property OnDblClick;
    property OnDragDrop;
    property OnDragOver;
    property OnEndDrag;
    property OnEnter;
    property OnExit;
    property OnMouseDown;
    property OnMouseMove;
    property OnMouseUp;
    property OnStartDrag;
  end;

implementation

{ TFlatGroupBox }

constructor TFlatGroupBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls, csOpaque];
  FBorderColor := $008396A0;
  FAdvColorBorder := 50;
  SetBounds(0, 0, 185, 105);
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.Paint;
var
  memoryBitmap: TBitmap;
  borderRect, textBounds: TRect;
  textHeight, textWidth: integer;
  Format: UINT;
begin
  borderRect := ClientRect;
  {$IFDEF DFS_COMPILER_4_UP}
  if BidiMode = bdRightToLeft then
    Format := DT_TOP or DT_RIGHT or DT_SINGLELINE
  else
    Format := DT_TOP or DT_LEFT or DT_SINGLELINE;
  {$ELSE}
  Format := DT_TOP or DT_LEFT or DT_SINGLELINE;
  {$ENDIF}

  memoryBitmap := TBitmap.Create; // create memory-bitmap to draw flicker-free
  try
    memoryBitmap.Height := ClientRect.Bottom;
    memoryBitmap.Width := ClientRect.Right;
    memoryBitmap.Canvas.Font := Self.Font;

    textHeight := memoryBitmap.canvas.TextHeight(caption);
    textWidth := memoryBitmap.Canvas.TextWidth(caption);

    {$IFDEF DFS_COMPILER_4_UP}
    if BidiMode = bdRightToLeft then
      textBounds := Rect(ClientRect.Right - 10 - textWidth, ClientRect.Top,
        ClientRect.Right - 10 , ClientRect.Top + textHeight)
    else
      textBounds := Rect(ClientRect.Left + 10, ClientRect.Top,
        ClientRect.Left + 10 + textWidth,
        ClientRect.Top + textHeight);
    {$ELSE}
    textBounds := Rect(ClientRect.Left + 10, ClientRect.Top,
      ClientRect.Left + 10 + textWidth,
      ClientRect.Top + textHeight);
    {$ENDIF}
    textBounds := Rect(ClientRect.Left + 10, ClientRect.Top,
      ClientRect.Right - 10,
      ClientRect.Top + textHeight);

    // Draw Background
    if FTransparent then
      DrawParentImage(Self, memoryBitmap.Canvas)
    else
    begin
      memoryBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := Self.Color;
      memoryBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
    end;

    // Draw Border
    memoryBitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color := FBorderColor;
    memoryBitmap.Canvas.Pen.Style := FBorderStyle;
    memoryBitmap.Canvas.Pen.Width := FBorderWidth;
    case FBorder of
      brFull:
        {$IFDEF DFS_COMPILER_4_UP}
        if BidiMode = bdRightToLeft then
          memoryBitmap.Canvas.Polyline([Point(ClientRect.Right - 15 - textWidth, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)),
            Point(ClientRect.left, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)),
            Point(ClientRect.left, ClientRect.bottom-1), Point(ClientRect.right-1, ClientRect.bottom-1),
            Point(ClientRect.right-1, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)),
            Point(ClientRect.Right - 7 , ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2))])
        else
          memoryBitmap.Canvas.Polyline([Point(ClientRect.left + 5, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)),
            Point(ClientRect.left, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)),
            Point(ClientRect.left, ClientRect.bottom-1), Point(ClientRect.right-1, ClientRect.bottom-1),
            Point(ClientRect.right-1, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)),
            Point(ClientRect.left + 12 + textWidth, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2))]);
        {$ELSE}
        memoryBitmap.Canvas.Polyline([Point(ClientRect.left + 5, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)),
          Point(ClientRect.left, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)),
          Point(ClientRect.left, ClientRect.bottom-1), Point(ClientRect.right-1, ClientRect.bottom-1),
          Point(ClientRect.right-1, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)),
          Point(ClientRect.left + 12 + textWidth, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2))]);
        {$ENDIF}
      brOnlyTopLine:
        {$IFDEF DFS_COMPILER_4_UP}
        if BidiMode = bdRightToLeft then
        begin
          memoryBitmap.Canvas.Polyline([Point(ClientRect.right - 5, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)), Point(ClientRect.right, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2))]);
          memoryBitmap.Canvas.Polyline([Point(ClientRect.left+1, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)), Point(ClientRect.right - 12 - textWidth, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2))]);
        end
        else
        begin
          memoryBitmap.Canvas.Polyline([Point(ClientRect.left + 5, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)), Point(ClientRect.left, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2))]);
          memoryBitmap.Canvas.Polyline([Point(ClientRect.right-1, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)), Point(ClientRect.left + 12 + textWidth, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2))]);
        end;
        {$ELSE}
        begin
          memoryBitmap.Canvas.Polyline([Point(ClientRect.left + 5, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)), Point(ClientRect.left, ClientRect.top + (Canvas.textHeight(caption) div 2))]);
          memoryBitmap.Canvas.Polyline([Point(ClientRect.right-1, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2)), Point(ClientRect.left + 12 + textWidth, ClientRect.top + (textHeight div 2))]);
        end;
        {$ENDIF}
    end;

    // Draw Text
    memoryBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    if not Enabled then
    begin
      OffsetRect(textBounds, 1, 1);
      memoryBitmap.Canvas.Font.Color := clBtnHighlight;
      DrawText(memoryBitmap.Canvas.Handle, PChar(Caption), Length(Caption), textBounds, Format);
      OffsetRect(textBounds, -1, -1);
      memoryBitmap.Canvas.Font.Color := clBtnShadow;
      DrawText(memoryBitmap.Canvas.Handle, PChar(Caption), Length(Caption), textBounds, Format);
    end
    else
      DrawText(memoryBitmap.Canvas.Handle, PChar(Caption), Length(Caption), textBounds, Format);

    // Copy memoryBitmap to screen
    canvas.CopyRect(ClientRect, memoryBitmap.canvas, ClientRect);
  finally
    memoryBitmap.free; // delete the bitmap
  end;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.CMTextChanged (var Message: TWmNoParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.SetColors(const Index: Integer;
  const Value: TColor);
begin
  case Index of
    0: FBorderColor := Value;
  end;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.SetBorder(const Value: TGroupBoxBorder);
begin
  FBorder := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.SetAdvColors(Index: Integer; Value: TAdvColors);
begin
  case Index of
    0: FAdvColorBorder := Value;
  end;
  CalcAdvColors;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.SetUseAdvColors(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if Value <> FUseAdvColors then
  begin
    FUseAdvColors := Value;
    ParentColor := Value;
    CalcAdvColors;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.CalcAdvColors;
begin
  if FUseAdvColors then
  begin
    FBorderColor := CalcAdvancedColor(Color, FBorderColor, FAdvColorBorder, darken);
  end;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.CMParentColorChanged(var Message: TWMNoParams);
begin
  inherited;
  if FUseAdvColors then
  begin
    ParentColor := True;
    CalcAdvColors;
  end;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.CMSysColorChange(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if FUseAdvColors then
  begin
    ParentColor := True;
    CalcAdvColors;
  end;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.CMDialogChar(var Message: TCMDialogChar);
begin
  with Message do
    if IsAccel(Message.CharCode, Caption) and CanFocus then
    begin
      SetFocus; 
      Result := 1;
    end;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.CMEnabledChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.SetTransparent(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FTransparent := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.SetBorderWidth(value:integer);
begin
  FBorderWidth := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.SetBorderStyle(value:TPenStyle);
begin
  FBorderStyle := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.WMMove(var Message: TWMMove);
begin
  inherited;
  if FTransparent then
    Invalidate;
end;

procedure TFlatGroupBox.WMSize(var Message: TWMSize);
begin
  inherited;
  if FTransparent then
    Invalidate;
end;

{$IFDEF DFS_COMPILER_4_UP}
procedure TFlatGroupBox.SetBiDiMode(Value: TBiDiMode);
begin
  inherited;
  Invalidate;
end;
{$ENDIF}

end.
```

With the added features you can change the color of the border, the width, the style and have the choice to have no border at all by setting the border style to `psClear`.

regards Nasreddine.